# Render image in validate function - shiny

Tags: r, shiny

let's say a generic code of validate function of shiny R :

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  selectizeInput('in2', 'Select a state', choices = state.name),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$in1, 'Check at least one letter!'),
      need(input$in2 != '', 'Please choose a state.')
    )
    plot(1:10, main = paste(c(input$in1, input$in2), collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Could you think it's possible to replace mesage error in character ('Check at least one letter!') by an image (png, jpeg format) ? I tried with renderImage function or , with the help of package `imager`, and don't manage to do it.

many thanks to you,
echoes

Thanks you for your quick answer, it could be a great solution for my shiny application, and it works !

in :

```
tags$style(HTML("
  .shiny-output-error-validation {
    background-image: URL(https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
"))
```

It would be nice to display a random or personalized image, who depends on user action. shinipsum package offer a random_image function, which could be quoted, something as :

```
tags$style(HTML("
  .shiny-output-error-validation {
    background-image: plotOutput("random_image");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
"))
```

and in server part :

```
output$random_image <- renderImage({
random_image()
},deleteFile=FALSE)
```

Do you think it's possible to use output of ui part in tags$style or tagsList parts ?

many thanks, echoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random `ggplot`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinipsum)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    test <- need(input$in1, "")
    if(!is.null(test)) {
      random_ggplot()
    } else {
      plot(1:10, main = input$in1)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

A random image:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinipsum)
library(imager)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    test <- need(input$in1, "")
    if(!is.null(test)) {
      img <- load.image(random_image()$src)
      plot(img)
    } else {
      plot(1:10, main = input$in1)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ase they say in [this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) you can add css style to validation messages. Just target with the selector `.shiny-output-error-validation`.

In this case I rendernder stackoverflow logo as background to the validation html element.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .shiny-output-error-validation {
        background-image: URL(https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
    "))
    ),
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  selectizeInput('in2', 'Select a state', choices = state.name),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$in1, " ")
    )
    plot(1:10, main = paste(c(input$in1, input$in2), collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do something with css tags in two parts, part one here :

```
css_content1 <- "
.shiny-output-error-validation {
  background-image:"
writeLines(text = css_content1, con = "styles1.css")
css1 <- readLines(con = "styles1.css") %>% paste(collapse = "\n")
```

part two :

```
css_content2 <- "
background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
"
writeLines(text = css_content2, con = "styles2.css")
css2 <- readLines(con = "styles2.css") %>% paste(collapse = "\n")
```

I modify server file as below, using renderUi function :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$in1, " ")
    )
    plot(1:10, main = paste(c(input$in1, input$in2), collapse = ', '))
  })
            
  output$css_style <- renderUI({
    tags$head(      tags$style(HTML(paste0(css1,"URL(test",sample(1:4,1),".png);",css2,collapse="\n"))
    ))
    })
    
      
    output$css_style_text <- renderText({
    HTML(paste0(css1,"test",sample(1:4,1),".png",");",css2,collapse="\n"))    
    })
    
     
}
```

with test1.png, test2.png etc ... in a `www` directory.
I add in UI file part :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("css_style"),
  checkboxGroupInput('in1', 'Check some letters', choices = head(LETTERS)),
  selectizeInput('in2', 'Select a state', choices = state.name),
  plotOutput('plot') 
)
```

I didn't manage to use a random_image function from shinipsum package.
thanks for your help